# How to safely update Laravel queues without errors?

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue

I have a system with multiple web servers behind a load balancer.  I also have one or more servers for running queued jobs (each server can also have more than one queue listener). The web servers push jobs on to redis (separate server) and the workers pull the jobs.

I'm trying to find the best way to update the code (git pull) in each of these locations without the workers having failed jobs due to code changes. An example would be removing a dependency.  Queued jobs would still rely on the "old" code after running git pull.  Thus, the job would error out since the dependency was removed.

Does anyone have insight on updating the queue workers without causing jobs to fail?

Comment: why not setup a cron job to git pull on a regular basis?

Comment: The new code could still break queue jobs that haven't been executed yet.